# Unpack QNX .img files

Tags: qnx

I am currently investigating firmware of an embedded system (car navigation) and have identified the OS as QNX.

The firmware has .ifs files which I was able to extract/unpack using QNX [dumpifs](http://www.qnx.com/developers/docs/660/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.qnx.doc.neutrino.user_guide%2Ftopic%2Ffiles_FILEEXTENSIONS.html) tool and .img files. The .img files do not appear to be compressed, is there a file format or dump tool for QNX .img files?

/edit: some extra information
file -sL file.img reports `x86 boot sector`
Mount attempt in Ubuntu `mount -t qnx6 ./file.img -o loop/dev/loop1,blocksize=512 /media/qnx` fails with wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/loop1

dmesg reports `qnx4: wrong fsid in superblock` or `qnx6: invalid mount operation`

`cat /proc/filesystems` reports both qnx4 and qnx6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Last time I worked with .img file it was image of qnx6 file system.
I using linux with installed qnx6 drivers, so mount -t qnx6 works for me.

In addition you can download QNX sample virtual machine from qnx.com/download/index.html ,run it, mount img using standard qnx command line tools and scp it outside.

Comment: Is there a distribution that supports qnx6 out of the box? RHEL/Centos don't seem to have any qnx support, and Ubuntu has qnx4, but no qnx6, apparently.

Comment: Sorry, I have gentoo, it supports everything from the box if configured properly. In addition you can download sample VM of qnx 6.5 (http://www.qnx.com/download/index.html) and scp mounted data outside from there.

Comment: Here is a direct download link for the Zipped VMware image of QNX Neutrino 6.5.0 Runtime environment: http://www.qnx.com/download/feature.html?programid=20725

Comment: @ws tried your suggestions but doesn't work for me (see edit), also installed QNX VM but how to transfer .img file to the VM (network doesn't work on VMware Workstation). Any ideas?

Comment: mount -t qnx6 works in QNX VM so am able to access the files now but would be much easier from Linux :D

Comment: @Remko I used mount -o loop -t qnx6 [image] [location] to mount it (loop was without additional options). Networking works for me, so I have no additional suggestions. file utility outputs the same  (x86 boot sector).